# 3. degree polynomial for a ramp between two horizontal lines

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have a the following exercises: I have a ramp that has to be described by 3. degree polynomial. The ramp has the height 80 cm and the polynomial cant't have a greater slope then 10 degrees. I have to figure out what the distance do I need for polynomial function?

I thought I would do this with linear equations and some knowledge in derivatives. The equations I came up with are:

$
0=d \\ 
80 = ax³+bx²+cx+d \\
0=c \\
0 = 3ax²+2bx+c\\
0=6ax+2b\\
\frac{1}{10}=3ax²+2bx+c
$

Am I missing something because I kind of can't calculate a and b from these equations?

Comment: 1) Do your ramp is assumed to extend from the origin 0 (with $x_0=0$) to the right until a certain $x_1$ (it is important to distinguish this **final** $x_1$ from the current $x$. 2) Why $c=0$ ? 3) Your assumption of second derivative =0 has no base 3) $3ax^2+2bx+c \leq \tan(10°)$ for all $x \in [x_0,x_1]$

Comment: 1) I guess it would be the easiest way if its origin is 0.  2) c = 0 because the derivative at the point where ramp ends is 0 (at a height of 80 cm)

Comment: OK you are right for $c=0$. I see a solution to your problem I am going to write down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to tackle less parameters from the beginning, let us consider the third degree **odd** function with this equation depending on two parameters $a,m$, assumed $>0$:

$$y=f(x)=-ax(x-m)(x+m)=-ax(x^2-m^2)=-ax^3+am^2x.$$

Its graphical representation can be seen below for the value of parameters given by (6). As

$$\tag{1}f'(x)=-3ax^2+am^2=a(m^2-3x^2)$$

we have two values for which $f'(x)=0$:

$$\tag{2} f'(\pm p)=0 \ \ \text{iff} \ \  p:=\frac{m}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

An immediate study of the sign of $f$ (successively $<0,>0,<0$) shows that there is a local minimum $A$ (resp. local maximum $B$) which will be the starting point (resp. the end point).

As we want an overall total altitude shift equal to $0.8$ metres, we have:

$$A(-p,-0.4)=(-\frac{m}{\sqrt{3}},-0.4) \ \ \text{and} \ \ B(p,0.4)=(\frac{m}{\sqrt{3}},0.4).$$

Thus, we have in particular:

$$f(p)=0.4 \ \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \ -a\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\frac{m^2}{3}-m^2\right)=0.4$$

yielding the following relationship between parameters $a$ and $m$:

$$\tag{3}am^3=0.6 \sqrt{3}.$$

Besides, as, for $x \in [-p,p]$, $f'(x)$  is maximum in $0$, with value $f'(0)=am^2$, the constraint on slopes is

$$\tag{4}am^2 \leq \tan(10^{\circ}).$$

that can be transformed, using (3), into

$$m \geq \frac{0.6\sqrt{3}}{\tan{(10^{\circ}})}=5.89377.$$

Thus, the answer to the minimal **horizontal** distance needed to build this "access ramp" is:

$$\tag{5} d=2p=\frac{2m}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1.2}{\tan{(10^{\circ}})}=6.80554...\approx 6.80 \ \text{metres}$$

Taking (4) into account (i.e., $a \leq \frac{\tan(10^{\circ})}{m^2}$), here is a proposal for a solution:

$$\tag{6} m=6 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ a=0.0049.$$

Remark: if one desires to start from the origin, it suffices to replace $y=f(x)$ by its shifted version: $y=f(x-m)+0.4.$

[image]